# Camera calibrated to/into/? optimal settings

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am trying to figure out what the correct preposition would be (and why):

> Camera calibrated to/into/? optimal settings

Thanks

Comment: One doesn't normally use *calibrate* like that at all. Could you edit the question to expand on what "calibration" involves here? I suspect that what you are doing requires a different verb altogether.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I suspect the verb in question may be 'configure'.

Comment: One usually calibrates an instrument *to* something. Not *into*, which would imply a transformation out of type.

Comment: Or one might calibrate an instrument *against* a standard, which tells you how much you need to *adjust* it by.

Comment: Check out the meaning of *calibrate* to start with.

Comment: Thanks. By calibration I mean the meaning as used with instruments and devices. So not sure what correct phrasing should be.

Comment: For instruments and devices, calibrate when used with a preposition is almost always with 'to'. And as Andrew pointed out, 'against' is used as well.

Comment: To clarify: *calibrating* a camera with respect to, say, focal distance is *not* just a matter of setting the focus adjustment to "3m" for an object measured to be three meters in front of the lens; it is a matter of confirming that the "3m" focus setting is indeed exactly right for that precisely and accurately measured distance, as opposed to being the setting for perfect focus at 2.9 or 3.1 meters.

Comment: The point that others are trying to make, and I don't think you are getting yet, is this: Calibration is not just configuring - setting some individually preferred values as defaults. It is about bringing an instrument in line with a **standard**.  If you calibrate your bathroom scale then you adjust it so that it measures weight accurately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think calibrate is the word you want, as calibrate implies some external standard you're trying to match (as in calibrating measuring equipment). You might want to use **configure** or **set** instead, if you're talking about particular settings.